# MySQL query to get count in a range

Tags: mysql, sql, database

A snapshot of my DB

[image]

I want to get count of `pcl_No` present in a specified range( `SUM(tv_land + tv_imp)`)

I have written a query but I am getting Invalid use of group error

```
select
 count(CASE WHEN sum(tv_land+tv_imp) BETWEEN 0 AND 10000 THEN 1 END) as count0_10000
    from
tax_l2006
where red_date = 0
GROUP BY pcl_no
```

Sample Output

`0-10000     10000-20000     30000-40000     >40000
  2              3             1              8`

Comment: Your data suggests that `pcl_no` is unique.  Are there every duplicates?

Comment: `pcl_no` is unique in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want:

```
select count(CASE WHEN tv_land + tv_imp BETWEEN 0 AND 10000 THEN 1 END) as count0_10000
from tax_l2006
where red_date = 0;
```

I would write this in MySQL more simply as:

```
select sum( (tv_land + tv_imp) between 0 and 10000 ) as count0_10000
from tax_l2006
where red_date = 0;
```

MySQL treats a true boolean as "1" in a numeric context and "0" for false, so summing the boolean is counting the number of times it is true.

You can follow the same pattern for the rest of the columns.

*If* `pcl_no` is not unique and you need to sum the values, then you would use a subquery:

```
select sum(total between 0 and 10000) as count0_10000
from (select pcl_no, sum(tv_land + tv_imp) as total
      from tax_l2006
      where red_date = 0
      group by pcl_no
     ) p;
```

However, your data suggests that the column is unique, so the additional aggregation is not necessary.